# css animations on mouse direction?

Tags: css, animation, mouse, direction

I am looking for a way to animate a picture using CSS.
My goal is to make the picture move the same direction as the mouse on the page.
If my mouse goes up, the picture goes up, if I move right, it goes right, the same for up and down.

Is it possible ? And if it is how can I do it ?

Thanks

Comment: what did you try so far ? Read [ask] plz ;)

Comment: With jquery http://jsfiddle.net/3ob3tu7f/

Answer (score 0):

only with pure css I am not sure if its possible, but look at this answer here which might give you a good lead

[images move dependently of mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376576/images-move-dependently-of-mouse-position)